# Error with variant variable in regression output

Tags: excel, economics, vba

I have a macro which is written to perform an OLS regression on data that is selected by the user. This is part of a larger add in that I am writing but I am stuck on what I think must be somewhat of a simple issue. I keep getting a subscript out of range error and I think its because I am getting a different sized matrix to what I am expecting.

The sub takes two variables as its arguments and calculated the OLS estimator given the specification. The y variable is always a n x 1 range (one column and multiple row) and the X variable is a n x m range (can be multiple columns and rows). When this function is used when X is a single column range, the `For... Next` block works for the following code:

```
For bcnt = 1 To k
    Cells(bcnt, 1).Value = b(bcnt)
Next bcnt
```

But if the X variable is a multiple column range this won't work and it has to be the following:

```
For bcnt = 1 To k
    Cells(bcnt, 1).Value = b(bcnt,1)
Next bcnt
```

I can't understand why as by my understanding `b` should always be a one dimensional array.

Would appreciate any help.

**The actual sub:**

```
Sub OLSregress(y As Variant, X As Variant)
Dim Xtrans, XtransX, XtransXinv, Xtransy As Variant
Dim outputsheet As Worksheet
Dim b As Variant

' The equation for this estimator is b=[X'X]^(-1)X'Y


Xtrans = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(X)
XtransX = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(Xtrans, X)
XtransXinv = Application.WorksheetFunction.MInverse(XtransX)
Xtransy = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(Xtrans, y)
b = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(XtransXinv, Xtransy)
k = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(b)

Set ouputsheet = Sheets.Add(, ActiveSheet)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Regression Output"
For bcnt = 1 To k
    Cells(bcnt, 1).Value = b(bcnt, 1)
Next bcnt

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are referring to a range or are bringing in data from a sheet the array is always a 2 dimensional array.  The first dimension is rows and the second is the columns.

This is a common point of confusion in VBA for excel because it's done without your intervention.

---

Your code is correct.

For more in-depth information check out this [post](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: So is there anyway to convert the 2 dimensional array to a one dimensional array? At the moment I just used error handling to get around it.

Comment: Looping through one and assigning to the other is the only way I'm aware of that VBA would support.